# Perfview - highest samples at Process row in CPU stacks

Tags: .net, performance, debugging, perfview

I'm measuring our custom tool that parses log files. 
The CPU stack looks like this:

[image]

**The Process32 LogScanner has 231505 exclusive samples.
What that might mean?**

I usually see `ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart` frame when measuing other applications and there are a lot of threads and the app is CPU intensive.

Comment: according to the picture the IsMatch function uses most CPU. for CPU usage analysis you should use WPA.exe from Windows Performance Toolkit.

Comment: I know that it's IsMatch method. But I suspect that there is a lot of other work (context switching?) that is related to poorly written program, because there are a lot of threads (using regexes) fighting with each other to get time to work.

Comment: use WPA, here you can activate a Stack Tag column and this shows context switches

Comment: here you can see how Stacktag looks in WPA: http://i.stack.imgur.com/l66jf.png

Comment: Might be useful - any good source talking about stack tags related to context switches?

Comment: context switches should show up under System. you can define your own stack tags: https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/stack-tags